# Code making SIGSEGV in GCC but not Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, segmentation-fault

This code generates a SIGSEGV on runtime when compiled with GCC (4.7.2-5ubuntu) but not Clang (Apple LLVM 4.2)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using FuncType = std::function<int(int)>;

int func(FuncType f, int i) {
    return f(i)+1;
}

struct Alpha {
    FuncType f, g;
    Alpha(FuncType f) : f(f) {
        g = [&](int i) -> int {
            return func(f, i);
        };
    }
    int go(int i) {
        return g(i);
    }
};

struct Beta {
    int k = 0;
    Beta newBeta(int nk) {
        Beta beta = *this;
        beta.k = nk;
        return beta;
    }
};

struct Gamma {
    Beta beta;
    void go(int j) {
        auto f = [&](int i) -> int {
            int n = beta.newBeta(i).k+j;
            return n*n;
        };
        Alpha alpha(f);
        std::cout << alpha.go(beta.k) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Gamma gamma;
    gamma.go(7);
    return 0;
}
```

Debugging, the crash occurs when the lambda `f` is called in `func`. `beta` reports as an invalid object, even though it should still be valid when the lambda is called.

It looks as though this is a result of [this bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53137), but that bug was reportedly fixed in 4.7.2.

**Edit:** Initialized `Beta::k` for clarity, does not affect bug.

Comment: Well, you're causing UB in `Beta beta = *this` because `k` is uninitialised in `Gamma::beta`. But I doubt that'd give you a segfault.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Good catch. Actually I'd say UB shows up even before, when doing `beta.k` in `alpha.go(beta.k)` inside function `Gamma::go()`.

Comment: @AndyProwl yep (though UB is retroactive so there is no "before"). Initialising `Beta::k` makes the program print 50 every time instead of some random number. And I don't get a segfault in GCC 4.7.2 or Clang 3.2 on LWS.

Comment: Hrm. `Beta::k` was left uninitialized out of laziness, it'll just default to whatever memory was there (as is the behaviour in Clang). However, this is just pared-down version of the code where I first discovered the problem, which does have the analog of `k` initialized, so I don't think that's the case.

@SethCarnegie What's your GCC source? I'm using the ubuntu-toolchain-r PPA for Quantal, but that might not actually be the latest 4.7.2 build.

Comment: The bug report you linked to mentions that the 4.7.2 fix didn't actually fix the bug and there were a couple of post-4.7.2 patches made.

Comment: @MikeBarriault no, it only _might_ default to whatever was there. It's undefined behaviour, which means anything can happen. And I just used the one from LiveWorkSpace (with initialisation): http://liveworkspace.org/code/xzkYe$1 But yeah, probably Michael Burr is right and the bug is just not fixed for your compiler.

Comment: After restructuring the original code to work around the bug, I discover that having the argument to `Alpha::Alpha` with a different name as the member also avoids the bug.

Comment: Upon further looking, it might not be a bug after all. I'm passing in the lambda to `Alpha` by value, which `g` captures by reference during construction, but that particular value is lost when it goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.

Comment: I'm surprised that `Alpha::Alpha(FuncType f) : f(f) { ... }` should be legal. If it is, I'm not surprised that some compilers get that wrong. Best to avoid name duplicates. Same happens again in the construction of `g`: which `f` is called here? the member or the argument? It's the argument, but you surely intended the member.

Comment: @Walter I don't agree that one needs to avoid name duplicates here. Using the same name for the constructor argument as the target class member usually makes sense. It's obfuscating your code otherwise and it's annoying to have to make up different names for essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

One problem is here:

```
Alpha(FuncType f) : f(f) {
    g = [&](int i) -> int {
        return func(f, i);
    };
}
```

your lambda is binding `f` (an argument to the contructor and so local to the constructor) by reference, so after the constructor completes, that reference is dangling.  When you later call `g`, you get undefined behavior as it refers to this dangling reference.

Change the `[&]` to `[=]` to bind by value and it should be ok.

Comment: Alternatively, the parameter to the `Alpha()` constructor can be renamed so the `f` in the lambda will refer to the `Alpha::f` member: `Alpha(FuncType ff) : f(ff) { ...`

Comment: This answer deserves many upvotes. I have no idea how I would have debugged this. VS2012's debug build caught the problem in the runtime with a `std::bad_function_call` exception, but the call stack was useless to me being able to figure out what the problem was.